# simple plan - schema database

Tags: php, mysql, database, schema

I would like to make a simple plan:
[image]
I did something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `plan` (
  `id` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `a` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `b` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `c` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `d` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `e` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;
```

but it doesn't work too well...

I wish that every cell has a unique ID in TD.

Now is:

```
    foreach($rows as $row)
    {
          
          id(); ?>>id() ?>
          id(); ?>>A() ?>
          id(); ?>>B() ?>
          id(); ?>>C() ?>
          id(); ?>>D() ?>
          id(); ?>>E() ?>
            
    }
```

and now i can't refer to a single TD. i wold like edit for example only ID: 20.

how best plan database?

thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every cell/`<td>` doesn't need an ID. Put the ID on the row/`<tr>`, as you've done in your database schema.

After that it should be a trivial task to identify the different columns per row.

The database:

```
| id | a | b | c | d | e |
--------------------------
| 1  | t | t | t | t | t |
```

The HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>a</th>
        <th>b</th>
        <th>c</th>
        <th>d</th>
        <th>e</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="id-1">
        <td class="id">1</td>
        <td class="a">t</td>
        <td class="b">t</td>
        <td class="c">t</td>
        <td class="d">t</td>
        <td class="e">t</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="id-2">
        <td class="id">2</td>
        <td class="a">u</td>
        <td class="b">u</td>
        <td class="c">u</td>
        <td class="d">u</td>
        <td class="e">u</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Or I've misunderstood you ;)

Comment: thanks, but now:   <pre>
id | a | b | c | d | e
-----------------------
1  | t | t | t | t | t
2  | t | t | t | t | t
</pre>
for example: 1a == 2a, 1e == 2e, so i cant edit only 2e, but then edit also 1e

Comment: Sorry, made some edits. What was the problem? Your comment looks clipped.

Comment: You're not saying what the real problem is. Is there a MySQL issue? You can update "2e" by doing `UPDATE plan SET e = 'some new value' WHERE id = '2'`.

Comment: no:) i will have access for single TD through CSS. 
http://img824.imageshack.us/img824/2107/zzzzhq.png
i will add in CSS background-color: red only in ID:20, but realy id "ID:20" is  same as ID:19, ID:18, ID: 17, ID: 16

Comment: This should work, using my HTML above: `table tr.id-2 td.e {background-color: red}`